# Fn+F1 keystroke acts like Super+S

Tags: unity, keyboard

I don't know why, but I know it happening.

After realizing that both <kbd>Fn</kbd>+<kbd>F1</kbd> and <kbd>Super</kbd>+<kbd>S</kbd> switches between workspaces, I used `xev` and found out that Ubuntu senses <kbd>Fn</kbd>+<kbd>F1</kbd> as <kbd>Super</kbd>+<kbd>S</kbd>.

In other words, <kbd>Fn</kbd>+<kbd>F1</kbd> is interpreted *as the same keystroke*.

Why is this, and how do I fix it?

**Added Info**

- The Leopard shortcuts menu has neither <kbd>Fn</kbd>+<kbd>F1</kbd> nor <kbd>Super</kbd>+<kbd>S</kbd>
- When I bind a shortcut to <kbd>Fn</kbd>+<kbd>F1</kbd>, the workspace selection screen appears, and when I back out, I find it to be set to <kbd>Super</kbd>+<kbd>S</kbd>.

**Update**

Turns out that my computer's bios reset whether I needed to use the <kbd>Fn</kbd> key to activate special keys, and now after fixing it I need to press <kbd>Fn</kbd>+<kbd>F1</kbd>, which is shown on my keyboard to be the Search key.

Answer (score 0):

Navigate to <kbd>System Settings</kbd> -> <kbd>Keyboard</kbd> -> <kbd>Shortcuts</kbd>.

It should look like this:

[image]

There should be options available to configure the shortcuts there. Look for the <kbd>Super</kbd>+<kbd>S</kbd> shortcut and change it to <kbd>F1</kbd>.

Also, remember to change the <kbd>F1</kbd> shortcut to <kbd>Super</kbd>+<kbd>S</kbd> afterwards and that should sort out the problem.

Comment: Neither F1 nor Super+S shows on the leopard shortcuts, and when I bound F1 to a different, unrelated shortcut, it shows as Super+S, behaving exactly like `xev`.

Comment: Yes, I am aware that Super+S lets me switch workspaces; what I'm trying to say is that F1 behaves just like Super+S, *even being interpreted as the same keystroke.*